# Testing if an audio file is corrupted

Tags: audio, multimedia

I have a folder full of audio files. Some of them are corrupted: At some point while playing them, Clementine shows an error saying that it failed to parse the stream; VLC just stops playing without an error message. `cvlc` does not display anything either.

How can I identify these files in bulk?

Comment: [MP3 Diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/) is a comprehensive application that can identify up to 50 types of issues with MP3 files and also has tools to fix most of those issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of libraries and programs to validate or check the integrity of audio files.
 I normally use myself [MP3val](http://mp3val.sourceforge.net) for mp3 files.